# How to combine two classes/methods with the "same" code but different return types in Java? (w/ Springboot + swagger api)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger

I have two API class configs with different return types, but the same code (except for one type in the method for ApiClient) for getting their respective APIs. How do I combine these? Is there a way to make some other class with a getApi() method that Class1Config and Class2Config can both use to reduce redundant code? I specifically want and tried making one class that can take in either Bean of Class1Api and Class2Api and use either config's private variables to use in its getApi() method but I'm having a rough time. They also use different @Values in an application.properties file, but same variable names.

**Class1Config Class:**

```
@Configuration
public class **Class1Config** {

  @Value("#{${app.rest-template.connection-timeout}}")
  private int connectionTimeout;
  @Value("#{${app.rest-template.read-timeout}}")
  private int readTimeout;
  @Value("${server.ssl.**class1**-key-store:}")
  private String keyStorePath;
  @Value("${server.ssl.**class1**-key-store-password:}")
  private String keyStorePass;
  @Value("${server.ssl.key-store-type:}")
  private String keyStoreType;
  @Value("${**class1**.api.path:}")
  private String apiBasePath;

  @Bean(name = "**Class1**Api")
  @Primary
  public Class1DefaultApi getApi()
      throws IOException, UnrecoverableKeyException, CertificateException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException, KeyManagementException {
    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
    keyStore.load(new FileInputStream(keyStorePath), keyStorePass.toCharArray());

    SSLContext sslContext = new SSLContextBuilder().setProtocol("TLS")
        .loadKeyMaterial(keyStore, keyStorePass.toCharArray()).build();
    SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslConFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext);

    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(sslConFactory)
        .build();
    ClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(
        httpClient);
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);

    **Class1ApiClient** apiClient = new **Class1ApiClient**(restTemplate);
    apiClient.setBasePath(apiBasePath);

    return new Class1DefaultApi(apiClient);
  }

}
```

Class2Config is the exact same, except with using the number 2 instead of 1:
**Class2Config Class:**

```
@Configuration
public class **Class2Config** {

  @Value("#{${app.rest-template.connection-timeout}}")
  private int connectionTimeout;
  @Value("#{${app.rest-template.read-timeout}}")
  private int readTimeout;
  @Value("${server.ssl.**class2**-key-store:}")
  private String keyStorePath;
  @Value("${server.ssl.**class2**-key-store-password:}")
  private String keyStorePass;
  @Value("${server.ssl.key-store-type:}")
  private String keyStoreType;
  @Value("${**class2**.api.path:}")
  private String apiBasePath;

  @Bean(name = "**Class2**Api")
  @Primary
  public Class2DefaultApi getApi()
      throws IOException, UnrecoverableKeyException, CertificateException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException, KeyManagementException {
    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
    keyStore.load(new FileInputStream(keyStorePath), keyStorePass.toCharArray());

    SSLContext sslContext = new SSLContextBuilder().setProtocol("TLS")
        .loadKeyMaterial(keyStore, keyStorePass.toCharArray()).build();
    SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslConFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext);

    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(sslConFactory)
        .build();
    ClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(
        httpClient);
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);

    **Class2ApiClient** apiClient = new **Class2ApiClient**(restTemplate);
    apiClient.setBasePath(apiBasePath);

    return new Class2DefaultApi(apiClient);
  }

}
```

I tried using Object and Generic types for getApi(), but I couldn't figure out how to do it with differing @Bean and @Qualifiers. I also didn't want to use if statements to return either Class1 or Class2, I'm trying to make a Generic method that they can use to get the Api with their respective configs/variables. I'm not too familiar with Springboot, and tried looking up documentation regarding multiname/array name Beans and other similar situations, but had no luck. Any hints or actual solutions would be helpful, thank you, or any similar situations I may have missed on stack overflow. If Java had conditional imports/multi-inheritance this would be much easier :(

Comment: Just return `apiClient`, then let the calling code wrap it